# DS-Lite: Extended NAT binding table

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6, nat

I‘m trying to set up a DS-Lite AFTR. Because of the overlapping addresses of the tunnel connections to the B4s, a normal NAT table does not work (already tried `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`), as described in RFC 6333. An extended NAT table would also contain the source IPv6 address of the packet sent by the B4, which means the AFTR then knows which tunnel to use in order to forward the packet.

How to do that extension on Linux?

I‘m using a Debian based system (Ubuntu 18.04).

I‘m establishing tunnels using `ip tunnel add dslite mode ip4ip6 local <IPv6 address of AFTR> remote <IPv6 address of B4>`
The AFTR has the address 192.0.0.1/29 on each tunnel interface and the B4s have the address 192.0.0.2/29 on their tunnel interfaces.

Note: I notice a lack of resources on that topix which is a shame. This is exactly why I‘m asking here. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've actually done it now. Let me take you through the process of me setting it up. My configuration partly survives reboots.

First, I've tested this with 2 B4s, 1 AFTR and all the systems manually set up.

Also I assume that your AFTR has the IPv6 address `2000::1`, the first B4 has the address `2000::2` and the second one has the address `2000::3`. The WAN interface of the AFTR has the name `eth0` here.

Let's get into it now.

First, I created the tunnels on the AFTR and the B4s manually.

On the AFTR:

```
root@AFTR:~# ip tunnel add dslite mode ip4ip6 local 2000::1 remote 2000::2
root@AFTR:~# ip tunnel add dslite2 mode ip4ip6 local 2000::1 remote 2000::3
root@AFTR:~# ip link set dslite up; ip link set dslite2 up
root@AFTR:~# ip a add 192.0.0.1/29 dev dslite; ip a add 192.0.0.1/29 dev dslite2
```

Now we can already establish the tunnels on the B4s.
On B4 1:

```
root@B4-1:~# ip link set dslite up
root@B4-1:~# ip a add 192.0.0.2/29 dev dslite
root@B4-1:~# ip route add default via 192.0.0.1 dev dslite
```

On B4 2:

```
root@B4-2:~# ip link set dslite up
root@B4-2:~# ip a add 192.0.0.2/29 dev dslite
root@B4-2:~# ip route add default via 192.0.0.1 dev dslite
```

Now the tunnels are configured and up. But the NAT has not been implemented yet on the AFTR.

```
root@AFTR:~# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE (eth0 is the Internet side network card)
root@AFTR:~# echo "1 dslite" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
root@AFTR:~# ip route add default dev dslite table dslite
root@AFTR:~# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i dslite -j MARK --set-mark 1
root@AFTR:~# iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
root@AFTR:~# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
root@AFTR:~# ip rule add fwmark 1 iif eth0 table dslite
root@AFTR:~# echo "2 dslite2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
root@AFTR:~# ip route add default dev dslite2 table dslite2
root@AFTR:~# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i dslite2 -j MARK --set-mark 2
root@AFTR:~# ip rule add fwmark 2 iif eth0 table dslite2
root@AFTR:~# sysctl -w net.ipv4.fwmark_reflect=1
```

Now the B4s should be able to reach the IPv4 (and of course IPv6) Internet. But this doesn't mean that they can reach each other, don't forget that when experimenting.

It's finally solved...